# sysml - do activity with guard

Tags: state-machine, sysml

I must describe the operation of a pump that delivers a certain volume provided that the liquid is at the correct temperature. the cycle is started by a push of a button.

I wish to describe this operation by the diagram below

button                                        when (Q = 40ml)
-------------> | do [T> Tmini] / pump () | ------------------------>

do I have the right to use this notation?

the question can be summed up
Can we have a conditional action in a "do" of a state machine diagram

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the tool you are trying to do this in, I would think.  And after you do, I would recommend reading the SysML spec to better understand that you may be asking for a state machine diagram, or a sequence diagram, or a constraints specification on a constraints block within a parametric diagram.

I don't know, but this "answer" should illuminate enough for you to either figure it out yourself, or refine your questions :)  Good luck!

Comment: i want to describe with  state machine diagram

Comment: Then refine your question, please.  This sounds like you need to look up Triggers, Guards and signals IFF you are using a tool like MagicDraw.  SysML has many ways to achieve this with a state machine, but if you are already able to specify Q and T, you probably are better off with a parametric diagram.